# Convert Image to text using possibly less memory

Tags: javascript, html, image-processing

I was reading about [Canvas toDataUrl increases file size of image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9773154/canvas-todataurl-increases-file-size-of-image), as I used this method myself in my code. But it's really a big trouble for me if the size of image is getting bigger when it's represented in text.

So I wanted to ask you my dear friends : is there any alternative that will work better? Why the image is represented exactly in base64? Is there any other "bases" we can convert it to?

I need to keep lots of images using minimum of the memory...

**Is there any javascript approach (serverside library or any other method) to represent images in text form using possibly small amount of memory?**

Comment: Just use the binary representation... What's your application?

Comment: we are not your colleagues ... what backend language are you using? you dont have to save the image in the format toDataUrl uses.

Comment: I'ts for now a simple web app (php used serverside)... I use php now. I need to represent image in text format using possibly less memory...

Comment: Rob how can i get binary representation of the image? (i have document loaded, image objects are all loaded... how can i get text representation using javascript?)

Comment: To represent a binary (8bit = values from 0 to 255) image "stream" as text which is supposed to be "character encoding free" you can use only 6 bit of a byte (values from 0 to 63). So every chunk of 3 image bytes (3*8 bit = 24 bit) will have to be represented by 4 text bytes (4*6 bit = 24 bit). So the resulting file will always grow to about four thirds of the original file size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of possibilities:

- Convert the base64 string to a binary string (just decode the string ;) )
- Zip the string
- Store it in a UInt8Array
- Draw the image to a canvas (don't know about the memory footprint of canvas elements though..)

You can combine some of the options above.